# Can't understand the end of Game of Life

Tags: game-of-life

### [**Game of Life**](http://www.flipkart.com/funskool-game-life-board/p/itmda5vynhbmkanh)

[image: Game of Life]

I can't really understand the ending of this game. How do I become Bankrupt or become a Millionaire?

Also, should I buy stock and insurance? Tragedies happens very infrequently and these cost a lot.

Comment: The [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/life.pdf) make no mention of bankruptcy, but you can get loans from the bank and reduce your net wealth to $0 or less. You can choose to go to millionaire estates for the opportunity to take the 4 life tiles there (richest player), or choose the safer retirement.

Comment: Wait, this isn't about Conway's Game of Life?

Comment: @Joe: See the link from where I bought it.

Comment: @userØØ7 -- I know, Conway's Game of Life is something completely different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the 1977 version, basically you have two choices.

1. Try to win by having the most money. You move towards the Millionaire space.  Once everyone has reached one of the two end spaces, the person with the most money at the Millionaire space wins, UNLESS someone successfully completes choice 2.
2. Try to win by sheer dumb luck.  Pick a number between 1 and 10, then spin.  If you spin the number you chose, you immediately win and everyone else loses.  The game is over.  Otherwise, you lose.  Even if you end up having more money than anyone who goes to the Millionaire space, you have still lost if you tried for this option and didn't spin your number.

Answer (score 5):

The rules for The Game of Life have changed over time. In the [1977](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Life%281977vers%29.PDF) version the following happens when you reach the end (Day of Reckoning):

[image: 1977 Rules]

In the [1991](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Life,_the_game_of_%281991%29.pdf) and [2000](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Life_the_game_of_2000.PDF) versions the following happens when you reach the end (Retirement):

[image: 1991 Rules]

Comment: I don't know how but my game also have the  rule  in upper image(My game is bought just 5-6 months ago).Please explain what's it?

Comment: @userØØ7 it sounds like the rules in the upper image are exactly what @ bwarner describes in the other answer.

Comment: Doesn't the new version have the additional rule that you can't steal tiles from people in Countryside Acres?